# Minimum distance between two points of multiple arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have multiple arrays of shape (12,3). Suppose they are Q, V, R, S. These arrays are actually xyz coordinates (atomic symbols omitted) For a sample, I am trying to calculate the smallest distance between a particle in Q and a particle in V array. Apart from that, I want the xyz component of the smallest distance.
For a output distance and xyz component, I create two arrays and append distance and xyz components values to them. Here is my code,

```py
import numpy as np
xyz_QV=[]; r_QV=[]

def min_distance(A,B):
        diff=10**20
        for i in A:
            for j in B:
                k=np.linalg.norm(i-j)
                if  k < diff:
                    diff = k
                    #xyz_QV.append(i-j)
        xyz_QV.append(i-j)
        return diff
    print('r_min=',min_distance(V,Q))
    r_QV.append(min_distance(V,Q))
xyz_QV=np.array(xyz_QV)
print(xyz_QV)
print(r_QV)
```

I have checked manually that distance array is okay, but the xyz component I am getting is wrong and instead of one row of xyz, I am getting two rows.
Any help please.

Additionally, If I want to find the same for QS and RS, what do I need to modify in the function?

Thanks in Advance..

Edit 1: providing sample arrays

```py
Q = np.array([[ 0.71264532,  1.1209957 ,  0.06054078],
              [ 1.35784165,  1.98639917,  0.12773717],
              [ 1.25823573, -0.1592519 ,  0.12423352],
              [ 2.32495428, -0.28709988,  0.24674303],
              [ 0.42688496, -1.27452666,  0.04265043],
              [ 0.85044465, -2.26843268,  0.09474995]])

R = np.array([[ 0.42688496, -1.27452666,  0.04265043],
              [ 0.85044465, -2.26843268,  0.09474995],
              [-0.94957784, -1.11007406, -0.1003136 ],
              [-1.5944557 , -1.9762737 , -0.16371348],
              [-1.49552564,  0.17105056, -0.16154602],
              [-2.56378279,  0.29922115, -0.27370311]])

V = np.array([[ 1.82750755,  1.11126079,  3.25188149],
              [ 2.47235268,  1.97744454,  3.31563221],
              [ 2.37346068, -0.16989031,  3.31340122],
              [ 3.44166756, -0.29803736,  3.42614544],
              [ 1.5418112 , -1.28549041,  3.23475079],
              [ 1.9648929 , -2.27984284,  3.28440446]])
```

The output I am getting is

```py
r_min= 3.069280599179459
[[ 1.11444826 -0.01141016  3.18965451]
 [ 1.11444826 -0.01141016  3.18965451]]
[3.069280599179459]
```

Comment: First, don't use semicolons in Python. Second, please correct your indentation so it is clear what is inside and outside of the function definition. Finally, please give us example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: Also, please try to use more descriptive variable names than single letters.

Comment: Can you clarify which pairs you want to find the distance for? Is it all pairs of Q, V, R, S?

Comment: @MattDMo I am not getting errors. Okay, Let me share two sample inputs and output.

Comment: @ddejohn I have provided Q, R and V arrays. Can I get the minimum distances between Q-V , V-R and Q-R?

Comment: @PrasantaBandyopadhyay absolutely, see my solution.

Comment: @PrasantaBandyopadhyay updated my solution as well. please check the function part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are trying to find the minimum distance between every particle in Q and every particle in V. On top of that, you want to get those particles as well.

Here is a completely vectorized way of what you are trying to do.

1. You can use the same method `np.linalg.norm(particle1-particle2)`
2. You can create 2 addition axis in the Q and V matrix such that you have a way of broadcasting the operation you want to get a cross product between particles in Q and V.

```
Q    -> 12  , None , 3
V    -> None, 12   , 3
---------------------
Q-V  -> 12  , 12   , 3
---------------------
norm -> 12  , 12
---------------------
min  -> 1
```

3. Which results in  12, 12, 3 matrix which can be reduced with `np.linalg.norm` with `axis=-1` to a 12, 12 matrix. This is the distance between every 12 particles in Q vs every 12 ones in V.
4. Now, it's just a matter of finding the minimum in this matrix
5. To get the index in Q and index in V for particles that result in this minimum distance, you can use `np.unravel_index` to get them and then index Q and V post that.

```
#Creating 2 dummy lists of particles
Q = np.random.random((12,3))
V = np.random.random((12,3))

#distance between every particle in Q vs V (resuting in 12,12 matrix)
distances = np.linalg.norm(Q[:,None,:]-V[None,:,:], axis=-1) 

#Get index position for Q and V particles with min dist
idx = np.unravel_index(distances.argmin(), distances.shape)

#Find particle Q and particle V which result in min distance
particleQ, particleV = Q[idx[0]], V[idx[1]]

print(particleQ)
print(particleV)
```

```
[0.60751186 0.93177959 0.23249369]
[0.64406579 0.91601754 0.27724177]
```

To prove that these particles have the minimum distance between them.

```
print('Minimum distance between Q and V particles:', distances.min())
print('Distance between the above calculated particleQ & particleV', np.linalg.norm(particleQ-particleV))
```

```
Minimum distance between Q and V particles: 0.11540521863305497
Distance between the above calculated particleQ & particleV 0.11540521863305497
```

---

#### As a function

```
def find_dist(Q, V):
    #distance between every particle in Q vs V (resuting in 12,12 matrix)
    distances = np.linalg.norm(Q[:,None,:]-V[None,:,:], axis=-1) 
    idx = np.unravel_index(distances.argmin(), distances.shape)
    particleQ, particleV = Q[idx[0]], V[idx[1]]
    
    return distances.min(), (particleQ, particleV), distances

QR_min, QR_particles, _ = find_dist(Q,R)
QV_min, QV_particles, _ = find_dist(Q,V)
RV_min, RV_particles, _ = find_dist(R,V)

print('Arrays Q, R')
print('Min distance:', QR_min)
print('Particle with min distance Q', QR_particles[0])
print('Particle with min distance R', QR_particles[1])
print('')
print('Arrays Q, V')
print('Min distance:', QV_min)
print('Particle with min distance Q', QV_particles[0])
print('Particle with min distance V', QV_particles[1])
print('')
print('Arrays R, V')
print('Min distance:', RV_min)
print('Particle with min distance R', RV_particles[0])
print('Particle with min distance V', RV_particles[1])
print('')
```

```
Arrays Q, R
Min distance: 0.0
Particle with min distance Q [ 0.42688496 -1.27452666  0.04265043]
Particle with min distance R [ 0.42688496 -1.27452666  0.04265043]

Arrays Q, V
Min distance: 3.0692806011237583
Particle with min distance Q [ 2.32495428 -0.28709988  0.24674303]
Particle with min distance V [ 2.37346068 -0.16989031  3.31340122]

Arrays R, V
Min distance: 3.3621077448250167
Particle with min distance R [ 0.85044465 -2.26843268  0.09474995]
Particle with min distance V [ 1.5418112  -1.28549041  3.23475079]
```

Comment: @Akshay Sehgal, Thank you for your answer. Yes what you said about finding distances and creating a matrix will work. However I thought instead of creating a new matrix, if I find the distances and the save shortest within in an array, I will need less typing.

Comment: Ofcourse, that would be a good way but, you have to then ensure that you have multiple nested loops. which can be avoided by making the solution completely vectorized. I have added a function which you can use with your other arrays. Check this out.

Comment: @PrasantaBandyopadhyay, you are not creating a new array in this approach, you are simply aligning the arrays such that you can broadcast and do this operation without any need for an additional library outside numpy.

Comment: I have tried your work as a function. It works @Akshay. Many many thanks. However, some part of your code I can not understand since I am a novice. Thank you.

Comment: let me know, which parts are confusing, will be happy to assist.

Comment: THis part
return distances.min(), (particleA, particleB), distances


    QV_min, QV_particles, _ = find_dist(Q,V)

Comment: So the distance matrix is 12,12 matrix. I am returning 3 things here as output of the function. the minimum distance in the 12,12 matrix. the ParticleA and Particle B (x,y,z) responsible for the min distance. .. and the distance matrix of shape 12,12

Comment: When i use `QR_min, QR_particles, _ = find_dist(Q,R)`, i basically say that I want the first and the second values from the funciton and `_` is just to ignore the 3rd values which is the distance matrix (12,12)

Comment: so `QR_min` is the minimum distance between Q and R particles, `QR_particles` are the 2 particles from Q and R responsible for the min distance... and `_` is supposed to be the Q, R distance matrix, which is ignored since you dont want it as an output.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238010/discussion-between-prasanta-bandyopadhyay-and-akshay-sehgal).

Answer (score 2):

### A "clean" solution with scipy

You can get all pairwise distances between two arrays using scipy's `spatial.distance` module:

```py
# Standard library
from typing import Tuple
from itertools import combinations as combs

# Third party
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist


def min_dist_and_xyz(A: np.ndarray, B: np.ndarray) -> dict:
    """
    Calculates the distance between all possible pairs of points
    from `A` and `B`, returning the smallest of them.
    """
    AB_dist = cdist(A, B)
    A_i, B_i = np.unravel_index(AB_dist.argmin(), AB_dist.shape)
    return {"min_dist": AB_dist[A_i, B_i], "xyz": np.abs(A[A_i] - B[B_i])}


def all_min_dists(arrs: Tuple[np.ndarray], labels: str) -> dict:
    """
    Calculates the minimum distance out of all pairwise combinations
    of arrays in `arrs`.
    """
    distances = {}
    for (x_lbl, x), (y_lbl, y) in combs(dict(zip(labels, arrs)).items(), 2):
        distances[f"{x_lbl}{y_lbl}"] = min_dist_and_xyz(x, y)
    return distances
```

Usage (I rounded the output separately for the sake of displaying the data):

```py
>>> Q, V, R, S = np.random.random((4, 12, 3))
>>> all_min_dists(arrs=(Q, V, R, S), labels="QVRS")
{'QV': {'min_dist': 0.14817, 'xyz': array([0.13026, 0.04566, 0.05387])},
 'QR': {'min_dist': 0.06003, 'xyz': array([0.01459, 0.05818, 0.00255])},
 'QS': {'min_dist': 0.04912, 'xyz': array([0.03048, 0.02257, 0.03121])},
 'VR': {'min_dist': 0.18245, 'xyz': array([0.12439, 0.06326, 0.11754])},
 'VS': {'min_dist': 0.14755, 'xyz': array([0.02883, 0.12283, 0.0765 ])},
 'RS': {'min_dist': 0.13614, 'xyz': array([0.12737, 0.04761, 0.00664])}}
```

### A "pure" solution using only numpy

It's usually a fair assumption that those that use numpy also have scipy installed, but if for some reason you don't have scipy installed, and/or don't want to use scipy, here's a solution only using numpy and takes advantage of `np.einsum()`.

This works by taking the sum of the squared distances between all possible pairs of points in any two arrays and then only evaluating the square root once on the smallest of those values, in order to return the minimum distance (insight courtesy of Alain T).

```py
def min_dist_and_xyz(A, B):
    diff = A - B[:, None]
    sq_dist = np.einsum("ijk,ijk->ji", diff, diff)
    ai, bi = np.unravel_index(sq_dist.argmin(), sq_dist.shape)
    return {"min_dist": np.sqrt(sq_dist[ai, bi]), "xyz": np.abs(A[ai] - B[bi])}
```

Surprisingly, this "optimization" doesn't actually produce a faster solution over scipy's `cdist` in the case of large arrays:

```py
In [5]: Q, V = np.random.random((2, 100, 3))  # Q and V are (100, 3)

In [6]: %timeit with_einsum(Q, V)
136 µs ± 1.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit with_cdist(Q, V)
58 µs ± 646 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: @PrasantaBandyopadhyay what did you find insufficient about my answer?